# How to dispaly a login student written message in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display login student name and message.

after login student can write messages and send related to courses.the messages he send is displayed above in same page with his/her name and message

I got name, but message field fetches all messages that are in database. How to display a particular student name and message?

Here is my code

controller.erb

```js
class CourseQueriesController <ApplicationController
      def index 
        @course_queries = CourseQuery.all
        @course_query = CourseQuery.new
      end
      def create
       @course_query = CourseQuery.new(student_id: current_student.id, coach_id: "2", message: params[:course_query][:message]) 
        if @course_query.save
          redirect_to course_queries_path, notice: 'Query was successfully send.'
        else
          render :new
        end
      end
    end

    course_queries/index.html.erb

    <% @course_queries.each do |queries| %>
       <p><b><%= current_student.name %></b></p>
             <%= queries.message %>
    <% end %>
    <%= simple_form_for (@course_query) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :message %>  
      <%= f.button :submit , "Send or press enter"%>      
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Try `<%= current_student.queries.message %>`

Comment: i tried that . it shows error like this `undefined method `queries' for #<Student:0x007fe9da94d600>`

Comment: Can you post the associations between the models in the question please?

Comment: i added the association above . please check

Comment: And the student model also please

Comment: i updated above . please check

Comment: You should add `has_many :course_queries` to `student` model, then it should work

Comment: in Studend model add has_many :course_queries

Comment: same error `undefined method `queries' for #<Student:0x007f1477dd7e48>`

Comment: My bad. I've posted my answer.It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `has_many :course_queries` to the `Student` model

```
#student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_queries
  ...
end
```

And in the controller in `index` method change `@course_queries = CourseQuery.all` to `@course_queries = current_student.course_queries`

Now `<%= queries.message %>` will only display the `course_query`'s message of the `current_student`

Comment: thank you :) .it worked. you are helping me a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

> how to display a particular student name and message

You need to have the [relevant associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) established in your models, like what Pavan wrote.

I'll give you some more information on why this is important...

---

**ActiveRecord**

One of the main reasons Rails works so well is the way it helps you create & manage *objects*. In [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), objects form everything from your init commands to your user input responses, Ruby being a prime exponent of this structure.

Rails is built on Ruby, and therefore is object orientated too. *It* uses [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), the [MVC structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) & classes to give you a platform from which you can populate and manipulate objects:

[image]

Thus, you shouldn't be treating your application's interactions as a way to edit a database, or "display a login message" - it should be a way to invoke & manipulate *objects*.

Objects - in the case of Rails - are built in the `models`. The model data can then be used in the `controllers` and `views`.

This seems to be lacking in your code. If you can remedy it, your code will become a lot simpler and more powerful...

---

**Associations**

I'd do something like this:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :queries
    has_many :coarse_queries, through: :queries
end

#app/models/course.rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches
   has_many :queries
   has_many :student_queries, through: :queries
end

#app/models/coach.rb
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
   has_many :queries
end

#app/models/query.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :course
   belongs_to :student
   belongs_to :coach (maybe)
end
```

This structure will allow a student to send queries to specific courses, selecting the coach as necessary. Importantly, this sets up your *associations* so that you don't have to invoke multiple classes each time you want to populate the various objects.

```
#app/controllers/course_queries_controller.rb
class CourseQueriesController <ApplicationController
  def index 
    @queries = Query.all
    @query = current_student.queries.new
  end

  def create
    @query = current_student.queries.new query_params
    if @query.save
      redirect_to course_queries_path, notice: 'Query was successfully send.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def query_params
     params.require(:query).permit(:message).merge(coach_id: "2") 
  end
end

#app/views/queries/index.html.erb
<% @queries.each do |query| %>
   <p><b><%= query.student.name %></b></p>
         <%= query.message %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for @query do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :message %>       
  <%= f.button :submit , "Send or press enter"%>                        
<% end %>
```